# Access database with proper technique using jdbc connection inside the jsp file

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jdbc

I am learning Servlet and i would be thankful if anyone can help me with one issue. I want to make a jsp page which will retrieve the data from the database. As i heard, it is not good practice to access database inside the jsp file or we can say inside the view. Now other options are i can send data to my jsp file using request dispatcher, modelandview, session, cookies. but the problem is what if i am having too much data like 100 users details and i want to show it. I am working in spring framework. 
this is the code i used for my old application. Is there any batter way to do the same thing. Any help will be appreciated. Sorry for the bad English also i am just a learner. Thank you

```
 Connection con = DbConnection.myConnection();
                   Statement st = con.createStatement();
                   ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select patientId, patientName, phone, address, referredBy, organization from chimeral_labs.patient");

                   while(rs.next()){
                       out.println("<tr>");
                       out.println("<td><a href='patient.jsp?patientId="+rs.getString(1)+"'>CHIM"+rs.getString(1)+"</a></td>"); 
                       out.println("<td>" + rs.getString(2) + "</td>");
                       out.println("<td>" + rs.getString(3) + "</td>");
                       out.println("<td>" + rs.getString(4) + "</td>");
                       out.println("<td>" + rs.getString(5) + "</td>");
                       out.println("<td>" + rs.getString(6) + "</td>");
                       out.println("</tr>");
                   }st.close();
```

Comment: Yes there is. Go with how Spring MVC passes data from controller to JSP. As a start move your JDBC access code to Spring controller, wrap the result into a custom POJO, put it into ModelAndView and stop prematurely worrying about performance.

Comment: I am not sure about it but i think if i do that data will disappear if we refresh or reload the page. isn't it?

Comment: No it won't as the controller is invoked again and the data retrieved. Your view should be as dumb as possible and only be concerned with the viewing of the data not the retrieval.

Comment: Yeah i can understand now. I will try this and let you know if it is working